# Linear independence over $\mathbb{Z}_p^r$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Linearly independent vectors $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ over $\mathbb{Q}^r$ have integer coordinates. Prove they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}_p^r$ for almost every prime $p$. I've been thinking about this problem for a few days and couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Are you suggesting that $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ and $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3})$ are linearly dependent over $\Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: Vectors consist only of integers

Comment: I don't understand the close votes, the question is quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ denotes the matrix sending the standard basis vector $E_i$ to $X_i$, then linear independence is equivalent to $\det M \neq 0$.

What happens if $\det M \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for infinitely many primes $p$?